# How to save changed ComboBox value and display it as the ComboBox default value the next time that the page is loaded

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I need to save the Combo Box value which is changed by user during runtime and display it as the Combo Box default value the next time that the page is loaded. I am asking this for my UWP application. I have combo box defined in Settings.xaml as below:

```
<ComboBox Name="CLengthCombo" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
             <ComboBoxItem Content="24"/>
             <ComboBoxItem Content="25"/>
             <ComboBoxItem Content="26" IsSelected="True"/>
             <ComboBoxItem Content="27"/>
</ComboBox>
```

In my Settings.xaml.cs, I have defined a global variable named "localSettings_CycleLength" in order to save the changed combobox value so that it remains between application launches:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings_CycleLength = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

Then I have below code in my Settings.xaml.cs:

```
public Settings()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         if (localSettings_CycleLength.Values["CycleLength"] != null)
         {
             this.CLengthCombo.SelectedItem = localSettings_CycleLength.Values["CycleLength"];
         }
     }


 private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         var comboBoxItem = e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem;
         if (comboBoxItem == null) return;
         comboBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
         var content = comboBoxItem.Content as string;
         if (content != null)
         {
             localSettings_CycleLength.Values["CycleLength"] = content;
         }
    }
```

Now, the above code does NOT do what I need and I don't know why. Will you please help me?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing content of the selected `ComboBoxItem`. So you cant assign content to `SelectedItem`

You should do like this

```
if (localSettings_CycleLength.Values.ContainsKey("CycleLength"))
            {
                var savedItem = localSettings_CycleLength.Values["CycleLength"]; ;
                foreach(var item in CLengthCombo.Items)
                {
                    if((item as ComboBoxItem).Content.Equals(savedItem ))
                    {
                        this.CLengthCombo.SelectedItem = item;
                    }
                }
            }
```

And you have   `<ComboBoxItem Content="26" IsSelected="True"/>` in your xaml.So every-time you load the page 26 will be selected overwriting previously selected item